# Laravel 5.2 logout() is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

when i use make:auth on command to create simple authorize pages, i can loggin and register successful, but when i try to click on `logout` i get error, i used latest upadte laravel 5.2 and this is my `AuthController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            //@formatter:off
                'username'      => 'required|max:255',
                'name'          => 'required|max:255',
                'email'         => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password'      => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            //@formatter:on
        ]);
    }

    public function getLogout()
    {
            auth()->logout();

            return redirect()->route('/home');
    }  

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            //@formatter:off
            'username'  => $data['username'],
            'name'      => $data['name'],
            'email'     => $data['email'],
            'password'  => bcrypt($data['password']),
            //@formatter:on
        ]);
    }
}
```

i read more and more topic which have this problem, but solutions couldn't resolve my problem as adding

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

on routes or use `middleware` on `constructor`:

```
$this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
```

my link to logout on layout is:

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/auth/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
```

and i get this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 8912:
```

full stack error:

```
in compiled.php line 8912
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8264
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8212
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8207
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2419
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3286
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9948
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2366
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2350
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be: `Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');`

Comment: @felipsmartins yes, but it doesnt work and i get error

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your routes are caches, so you should try:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

to clear routes cache

or

```
php artisan route:cache
```

to clear cache and genarate new routes cache

Answer (score 0):

Try this for logout

```
Session::flush();
Auth::logout();
Cache::flush();
return Redirect::to('/home');
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Is it helpful for you?